# Too many arguments in method in udf, scala

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have udf function for calculating distance between 2 coordinates.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.math._

def  calculateDistance(la1:Double, lo1:Double,la2:Double,lo2:Double): Double   =>  udf(
{

val  R = 6373.0
val  lat1 = toRadians(la1)
val  lon1 = toRadians(lo1)
val  lat2 = toRadians(la2)
val  lon2 = toRadians(lo2)

val  dlon = lon2 - lon1
val  dlat = lat2 - lat1

val  a = pow(sin(dlat / 2),2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin(dlon / 2),2)
val  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

val  distance = R * c
}
)
```

Here is the dataframe schema .

```
dfcity: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [Name: string, LAT: double ... 10 more fields]
root
|-- SCITY: string (nullable = true)
|-- LAT: double (nullable = true)
|-- LON: double (nullable = true)
|-- ADD: integer (nullable = true)
|-- CODEA: integer (nullable = true)
|-- CODEB: integer (nullable = true)
|-- TCITY: string (nullable = true)
|-- TLAT: double (nullable = true)
|-- TLON: double (nullable = true)
|-- TADD: integer (nullable = true)
|-- TCODEA: integer (nullable = true)
|-- TCODEB: integer (nullable = true)
```

When trying using withColumn

```
val dfcitydistance = dfcity.withColumn("distance", calculateDistance($"LAT", $"LON",$"TLAT", $"TLON"))
it generates error:
6: error: too many arguments for method calculateDistance: (distance: Double)
```

What's wrong in the code the passing column to UDF? Please advise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of issues with your code:

```
def calculateDistance(la1:Double, lo1:Double, la2:Double, lo2:Double): Double => udf( {
  // ...
  val distance = R * c
} )
```

1. To create a UDF, you should wrap the entire Scala function as the argument for method [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@udf[RT,A1,A2,A3,A4](f:(A1,A2,A3,A4)=%3ERT)(implicitevidence$12:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[RT],implicitevidence$13:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A1],implicitevidence$14:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A2],implicitevidence$15:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A3],implicitevidence$16:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A4]):org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction).
2. In Scala, the last expression in your function body is what the function returns.  The expression `val distance = R * c` is an assignment, hence will return a `Unit`.  You should either append a line with just `distance` or simply replace the assignment expression with `R * c`.

Your UDF should look like the following:

```
val calculateDistance = udf( (la1:Double, lo1:Double, la2:Double, lo2:Double) => {
  // ...
  R * c
} )
```

Comment: thanks it is working so the problem is the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
val calculateDistance = udf((la1:Double, lo1:Double,la2:Double,lo2:Double) => {
  ...
})
```

The function you define right now is a functions which takes local objects and returns nullary UDF